# Автоматическое наполнение сайта

Tags: парсер

Наверное задам глупый вопрос. Как сделать чтобы парсер на Python в автоматическом режиме по времени осуществлял парсинг сайта-донора и затем вставлял эти результаты на мой сайт? Причем, чтобы мой ПК не участвовал в этом процессе. Интересно понять как организовать сам процесс.

Comment: не хотите, чтобы ваш ПК в этом участвовал - покупайте хостинг, там разворачивайте и сайт, и парсер, и что вашей душе угодно

Comment: Спасибо за ответ:)

Comment: Пишешь бесконечный цикл, пихаешь в него функцию с парсером и после того как закончилась итерация, уходишь в спячку на определенное тобой время. Можно сделать парсер асинхронным, что-бы занимало меньше времени, но перед этим нужно убедиться, что твой сервер выдержит нагрузку